# read child of child in firebase web (javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in firebase, how can i read child as in the image to my web page
anyone can tell me if there is a reference?

[image]

Comment: what child you want to read ?

Comment: child of colors ( 1 & 2 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read all colors of all nodes:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        childSnapshot.forEach(function(colorSnapshot) {
            console.log(childSnapshot.key+" - "+colorSnapshot.key+": "+colorSnapshot.val());
        });
    });
});
```

This prints:

> -LOIECwM70... - 1: red
>
> -LOIECwM70... - 2: blue
>
> -LOIEssdh1... - 1: green
>
> -LOIEssdh1... - 1: black

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value only when your data is in an object, then you can use

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();     //creating referense path
ref.once("value").then(data=>{
    let obj = data.val();
    for (let key in obj) {
        console.log(obj[key]);
    }   
})
```